# Why does my hr (Horizontal Rule) not show the supplied background?

Tags: html, css, background

I have this HTML:

```
<hr />
```

...and this CSS:

```
hr {
  background: url("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Mark_Twain#/media/File:Mark_Twain_photo_portrait,_Feb_7,_1871,_cropped_Repair.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Yet the hr only displays a normal line, no image. Even when I increase the height of the hr (by adding "*height: 200px;*" to the CSS), it just shows me an empty rectangle.

What do I have to do to get the image to display?

Comment: The problem is about the image url.

Comment: What are you tring to do that you're setting a photograph as the bg image of a `<hr>`?

Comment: @Shaggy: It was the first interesting image I found; on a real site, I would use a small image added to my project.

Comment: Ah, you're just trying it as a proof of concept, so to speak? Fair enough :)

Comment: @Shaggy: Yes, although I am a Twainiac/Twainologist, even I wouldn't use that image in an hr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two problems

1. The image you're linking to isn't an image URL. The actual image URL is `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Mark_Twain_photo_portrait%2C_Feb_7%2C_1871%2C_cropped_Repair.jpg`.
2. Even with the correct URL, `hr` elements by default have no height. They only have a 1 pixel width border. In order to display the image, you'll need to give your `hr` element some `height`.

#### Example

```css
hr {
  background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Mark_Twain_photo_portrait%2C_Feb_7%2C_1871%2C_cropped_Repair.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using links to a page, not an image. Click on the image on that page to give you the correct URL of `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Mark_Twain_photo_portrait%2C_Feb_7%2C_1871%2C_cropped_Repair.jpg`.

**EDIT:** Consider downloading that image and serving it up from a local URL (be sure to check the license first) as, if it gets deleted from or moved on Wikimedia, it will no longer display for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're pulling from Wikipedia's Media viewer. You'll need to link to the actual image file. Also, try adding a bit of height. Lastly, disabling the default border might also be something you'd want.

```
hr {
  height: 100px;
  border: 0;
  background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Mark_Twain_photo_portrait%2C_Feb_7%2C_1871%2C_cropped_Repair.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```